# C# XUnit Assert.Equal failing when comparing var and int

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, xunit.net

I have this snippet of test code:

```
public void Test () {
    var expected = 10;
    int actual = 10;
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);    //Failing
}
```

I understand that C#s var is implicitly typed, so it is recognized as an int during compile time; they should both be Int32. Would it not be comparing the values?

I also read that the `Equal` method compares objects; would this affect the way it compares the two primitive types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be comparing the values, and they should both be `int`s.

The impl of the various `Equal` overloads [should be in here](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/33d559b6496e1ccd054b76abe5faa12c4562473f/EqualityAsserts.cs).

If you clone the Asserts Lib (or the source repo for which I provided a submodule link) locally, you can step through the impl (or turn off Just My Code in Tools|Options - pretty sure xUnit's symbols are published somewhere).

Answer (score 2):

It works on my machine :)

But you miss the `[Fact]` annotation in your example, is it by mistake?

Comment: It is in my program, I just didn't mention it this post, thanks!